# Frameset problem in html

Tags: html, xhtml, dhtml

I have created a website with multiple no of pages with in a same folder (i mean all those pages are with in a folder). I have developed this design under the frames. I have used 3 frames top for banner, left side for menu and and right side for main page. While clicking the left side menu frame i just navigate the main page into different page.

My problem is while clicking the menu, i just change the target of the right side main frame. Is it possible to change the URL while navigating to different pages in the right frame.

Please guide me, How to proceed.

Thanks 
 Praveen

Comment: What do you mean by the URL doesn't change? Are you referring to the address bar URL?

Comment: No, i mean is it possible to change the url in respect of the page. Hope this is a blunder even though.. . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the URL without navigating to that URL.

You really don't want to use frames in the first place. Search engines (i.e. Google) wont index your site properly, users can't bookmark pages, and people just do not like frames, in the first place.

If you want to persist things like headers and sidebars across many pages without having to include the code in every single HTML file, you should consider using [server-side includes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/ssi.html).

Answer (score 1):

The question is still quite vague. As mentioned, you can use the target attribute to specify which frame to open a link in:

```
<a href="content.html" target="_content_frame">link</a>
```

You can use the HTML base target to specify a default target for all links (http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp):

```
<head>
<base href="http://www.w3schools.com/images/" />
<base target="_blank" />
</head>
```

I don't believe you can change the main page URL when changing an individual frame. You would be better off using a frameless layout to accomplish this. One benefit is that it's better for search indexing and for user bookmarks.