# Display frame url

Tags: html

I am developing a project, which is set up as follows,

It contains a frame with two columns:
--> First column (`Col1`) has the main menu (For example `CEO`, `HR`, `Staff`, `Clerk`,...)
--> Next column (`Col2`) has the corresponding content.

Now, when I click on the `"CEO"`, the corresponding page is loaded in the `Col2` just like it should, but the URL of the page remains same.

Is it possible to change the URL?
That is from say (`C:\\web\Masterpage.html`) to (`C:\\web\CEO.html`)

Please help me to find the solution.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676269/frameset-problem-in-html

Comment: you can use ajax call at time of onclick on first column

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change the URL of the loaded page just because an 'iframe' is getting changed.

But you could add in-page jumplinks or permalinks which will change the main URL
 from say `C:\\web\Masterpage.html` to `C:\\web\Masterpage.html#CEO` or `C:\\web\Masterpage.html#HR`

You can add jumplinks by adding `<div id="CEO" class="heading">CEO</div>` before the `<iframe>` tags and then changing the `href` location of your menu to `href="#CEO"`, `href="#HR"` and so on...

Run the code snippet below and when you hover over the links you'll see that the anchor ends in `#CEO`, `#HR` etc. The address displayed in browser's address-bar will be the same.

```js
var winLoc = window.location.href;

function writeFrame(y, p) {
  var Loc = winLoc + "#" + p;
  var y = document.getElementById(y).contentWindow.document;
  y.open();
  y.write("Content for " + p + " Goes here<br><br>The full URL of this page is:<br>" + Loc);
  y.close();
}

writeFrame("CEOframe", "CEO");
writeFrame("HRframe", "HR");
writeFrame("Staffframe", "Staff");
writeFrame("Clerkframe", "Clerk");
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: monospace;
}

ul {
  padding: 0 10%;
}

li {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.3em 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.mainContent {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: royalblue;
}

.heading {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  color: white;
}

iframe {
  width: 98%;
  height: calc(100vh - 3em);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainMenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#CEO">CEO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#HR">HR</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Staff">Staff</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Clerk">Clerk</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="mainContent">
  <div id="CEO" class="heading">CEO</div>
  <iframe id="CEOframe"></iframe>
  <div id="HR" class="heading">HR</div>
  <iframe id="HRframe"></iframe>
  <div id="Staff" class="heading">Staff</div>
  <iframe id="Staffframe"></iframe>
  <div id="Clerk" class="heading">Clerk</div>
  <iframe id="Clerkframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.

Peace

Answer (score 0):

The URL that is displayed is the URL or the page, and there is nothing that you can do about that. The only way to change the URL is to dispay a different page.

My advice would be to make the pages without a frameset. A frameset is usually more trouble than it's worth.